# Meaningful looking links instead of "index.php?page=pageName"

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have an index file that loads most of the visual parts of my page (header, footer, etc) and uses includes to fill in content from sub pages. Unfortunately, this means my links look like `domain/index.php?page=contact` rathar than `domain/contact`.

How would I go about achieving the latter structure in a good way?

Comment: No but it’s a great place to find answers and unhelpful sarcasm.

Comment: There's no sarcasm, just some comment against a lazy question (and "thisIsAUserName" is a lazy username ;) jk), which could have been easily unswered by searching on Google or, even better, directly typing in SO's search bar - as this question has been asked thousillions times

Answer (score 2):

read about .htaccess and mod_rewrite

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2):

[Apache's mod_rewrite](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting-) is what you're looking for. See page two for an easy to understand examples.

```
RewriteRule /domain/contact domain/index.php?page=contact
```